# Highest crossing number formed by a closed loop

Tags: geometry, polygons

I'm not certain about terminology here so bear with me please.

If you put three nails in a flat surface, then wrap a rubber band around them, you will never get any parts of the band to cross. (The rubber band has to touch each nail exactly once. For simplicity, let's assume that no three nails will be colinear.)

However, with $n = 4$ nails, there seems to be a way to get one crossing, but not more than one, by tracing out the crossed quadrilateral. (Crossings right by the nails don't count — think of nails as points on a plane.)

With five nails it seems like I can get up to five crossing if I trace out the pentagram. But can I get more crossings? For example, the (7/2) [heptagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagram) gives me 7 crossings, but I can also get 14 crossings using only 7 nails if I trace out the (7/3) heptagram.

In general, what is the name of these crossings, and can their number be easily calculated from the number of vertices (nails)?

Comment: I think you are mistaken for $n=3$. Say you have three nails forming an equilateral triangle. You put a rubber band across two of the nails. Now instead of pulling the side closer to the third nail, pull the other side and wrap it across the third nail. You now have $2$ crossings.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar yes but the two crossings are exactly at the vertices. I want the crossings to be further away, at different points.

Comment: It looks something like [this](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/K8h0xOn). Sorry for the bad and inappropriate looking image.

Comment: Oh, I thought [this](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/6xunIIn) was your interpretation for three nails. Anyway, if you want the crossings to not take place at the vertices, you should mention that in the question.

Comment: It turns out both links aren't working. Sorry I am not able to get my point to you.

Comment: This is the content of https://oeis.org/A105638 . If you'd find it useful and no one else has done so before then, I can write up a more detailed answer tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, thanks @TravisWillse! If you just write this down as an answer, I'll accept this, no need for a very detailed explanation as having the numbers is already very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grünbaum gave an explicit quasipolynomial formula for the maximal number $a(n)$ of self-intersections of an $n$-gon, $n \geq 3$:

$$a(n) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{n(n-3)}{2}, &\textrm{$n$ odd}\\
\frac{n(n-4)}{2}+1, &\textrm{$n$ even}.
\end{array}\right. ;$$
the first terms are:
$$0, 1, 5, 7, 14, 17, 27, 31, 44, 49, \ldots .$$
This sequence is [OEIS A105638](https://oeis.org/A105638), *Maximum number of intersections in self-intersecting $n$-gon*.

> B. Grünbaum, "Selfintersections of Polygons," *Geombinatorics*, **8**(4) (1998), 37-45.